# Is there a way to speed up garbage collection in IKVM?

Tags: java, .net, garbage-collection, ikvm

We have some code that we run in both Java and, using IKVM, in .NET. The Java code, the exact same source code, runs 5 - 10 times faster in Java.

The big difference we've seen is 30% or more of the time on the .NET side is in the garbage collector.

Is there something we can do to reduce the GC time?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your object lifecycle(s) and (for example) examine if you might use [flyweights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) or an [object pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) to minimize the number of object instances you create. The fewer instances you create, the fewer must be collected. Profile the code, look at the algorithms it employs and search for patterns that can minimize gc events (which you discover by profiling). You want a silver bullet, but if there was a silver bullet then it would presumably already be enabled.

Comment: Yeah, already doing that where we can. What's frustrating is it's not an issue under Java. And I doubt that natively .NET is that much worse when it comes to GC. So there's something about how IKVM does all this that impacts it. But as you said, if there was a solution, they would have turned it on.